# What is the simplest way to get the least value and second least value from multiple columns (MIN function does not work this)?

Tags: sql, teradata, sql-function

Below table is from Teradata database

```
SELECT
  sku.Item_id,
  sku.Item_length,
  sku.Item_width,
  sku.Item_heigth,
FROM  Category_item sku

Item_id | Item_length | Item_width |Item_heigth
-------------------------------------------
104174        8            6           1
9482763       8            8           8
8434610       8            9           1
2109145       54           34          2
567106        41           41          2
2028731       3            4           3
```

The final result that I want is,

```
 Item_id | Item_length | Item_width |Item_heigth | MinValue | SecondMinVale
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    104174        8            6           1          1            6
    9482763       8            8           8          8            8
    8434610       8            9           1          1            8
    2109145       54           34          2          2            34
    567106        41           41          2          2            41
    2028731       3            4           3          3            3
```

So I did a little research online, most of them used MIN function with a subquery or raw over by partition. Min function does not work for me, because I have three separate columns. I want to get minimum or least two values from the above three columns.

I tried to do subquery or CTE using Least function, but I am stuck with getting the second least value. I am not sure how to use raw over partition for this.

Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated.

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Your requirement is actually pretty hard to swing, but it would be much easier to handle if you had the various measurements across separate _rows_, instead of columns.  In that case, you could easily just use `ROW_NUMBER` to answer your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for the explanation, but I am going to use the above two values in the calculation on an automated report. So I don't have much flexibility over here.

Comment: Are you certain that all three values would always be different?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Nope. It can be all same too or two of the same. So it will not be always for different for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without set based analytic functions, your requirement is difficult.  I might suggest unpivoting your data:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Item_id, Item_length AS item FROM Category_item UNION ALL
    SELECT Item_id, Item_width FROM Category_item UNION ALL
    SELECT Item_id, Item_height FROM Category_item
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT Item_id, item,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item_id ORDER BY item) rn
    FROM cte
)

SELECT
    t1.Item_id,
    t1.Item_length,
    t1.Item_width,
    t1.Item_height,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN t2.item END) AS MinValue,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN t2.item END) AS SecondMinValue
FROM Category_item t1
INNER JOIN cte2 t2
    ON t1.Item_id = t2.Item_id
WHERE
    t2.rn <= 2
GROUP BY
    t1.Item_id,
    t1.Item_length,
    t1.Item_width,
    t1.Item_height;
```

Note that the need to use such unpivoting operations might seriously imply that your table should be redesigned with the various measurements being stored per item across *rows*, rather than across columns.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. I think this looks promising and I am going to try this and let you know. Unfortunately, I am not designing those tables, but I will have a chat with them. One last thing, this should work when all numbers are the same right.  Again thank you so much

Comment: @WeldaSucha Yes, this answer is robust to either a two-way or three-way tie (and in fact possible ties are the reason I am using this approach).

Comment: small issue. Some record its showing the same smallest number on both minvalue and secondMinvlaue even when they have a second min number. some records showing me completely different numbers. They are not even in the particular three columns. Do you know why is that?

Comment: for example, `Item_id Item_length Item_width Item_heigth MinValue SecondMinValue ' result according to above colunm orders '5650678 4 16 16 4 4` on tis one it is showing same vale, it should be 4 and 16.  `4348907 8 29 56 8 8` this is also the same.  `9033813 13 10 17 3 3` This one have complete different result. Do you know whay is that tho?

Comment: In Teradata you can skip right filtering on the window function results using the `QUALIFY` clause. Like `SELECT Item_Id, item, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item_id ORDER BY item) rn FROM cte QUALIFY rn <= 2`

Answer (score 1):

If you actually got three columns you can simply apply this brute-force logic:

```
SELECT sku.*,
   Least(Item_length,Item_width,Item_height) AS MinValue,
   CASE
     WHEN Item_length BETWEEN Least(Item_width, Item_height) AND 
                           Greatest(Item_width, Item_height) 
     THEN Item_length
     WHEN Item_width BETWEEN Least(Item_length, Item_height) AND 
                           Greatest(Item_length, Item_height) 
     THEN Item_width
     WHEN Item_height BETWEEN Least(Item_width, Item_length) AND 
                           Greatest(Item_width, Item_length)
     THEN Item_height
   END AS SecondMinValue
FROM  Category_item sku
```

For more than three columns you need Tim's approach, this is a slight variation (if your TD release supports UNPIVOT) avoiding the join-back:

```
WITH cte AS 
 (
   SELECT up.*
     ,Row_Number() Over (PARTITION BY item_id ORDER BY val) AS rn
   FROM Category_item
   UNPIVOT
    ( val 
      FOR measure
      IN (Item_length AS 'l'
         ,Item_width  AS 'w'
         ,Item_height AS 'h') 
    ) AS up
 )  
SELECT
    Item_id,
    Max(CASE WHEN measure = 'l' THEN val END) AS item_length,
    Max(CASE WHEN measure = 'w' THEN val END) AS item_width,
    Max(CASE WHEN measure = 'h' THEN val END) AS item_height,
    Max(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN val END) AS MINVALUE,
    Max(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN val END) AS SecondMinValue
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    Item_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

this below:

```
SELECT MIN(Item_caract)
      FROM (VALUES (Item_length),(Item_width),(Item_heigth)) a(Item_caract)
```

give you the minimum of all columns

and this:

```
(SELECT MIN(Item_caract)
      FROM (VALUES (Item_length),(Item_width),(Item_heigth)) a(Item_caract) where Item_caract >=
      (SELECT MIN(Item_caract)
      FROM (VALUES (Item_length),(Item_width),(Item_heigth)) a(Item_caract))
```

gives you the minimum that is bigger than the minimum above

Below is the full query:

```
select * ,

(SELECT MIN(Item_caract)
      FROM (VALUES (Item_length),(Item_width),(Item_heigth)) a(Item_caract))
   AS MinValue ,

(SELECT MIN(Item_caract)
      FROM (VALUES (Item_length),(Item_width),(Item_heigth)) a(Item_caract) where Item_caract >=
      (SELECT MIN(Item_caract)
      FROM (VALUES (Item_length),(Item_width),(Item_heigth)) a(Item_caract))
      )
   AS SecondMinVale 
from cte
```

Output:

```
104174  8   6   1   1   1
567106  41  41  2   2   2
2028731 3   4   3   3   3
2109145 54  34  2   2   2
8434610 8   9   1   1   1
9482763 8   8   8   8   8
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response. I am sure how values function works for me since I am getting all columns from table.  `SELECT MIN(Item_caract)
      FROM Category_item (VALUES (Item_length),(Item_width),(Item_heigth)) a(Item_caract)`
g

Comment: Besides the problem that Teradata doesn't support VALUES, your result is simply returning the lowest value in both colujmn :-)

Comment: Thanks dnoeth, will delete post